# Need to create a circuit that has two outputs, one output has half the voltage of the first output

Tags: circuit-design, potentiometer

I have two systems I am trying to get to work together.

One system has two inputs, input 1 takes an output from a potentiometer with a voltage ranging from 0.9 V - 4.5 V using a supply reference voltage of 5 V. The second input takes an output from a potentiometer ranging from 0.45 - 2.25 V. The output of the second potentiometer is always half the output from the first potentiometer. For safety reasons these inputs must remain independent.

These potentiometers are always physically locked together so that when one moves, the other one does too. The voltage from pot 2 is always half of pot 1 unless there is a failure. We will call this potentiometer assembly 1.

I am trying to interface with a different potentiometer, due to physical constraints I cannot use a potentiometer assembly other than this one.
We will call this potentiometer assembly 2. This potentiometer assembly works just like the assembly 1 but the value of output 2 is inverted, meaning as the pot is actuated the output #2 goes from 4.5 V to 0.9 V, the oposite of what is needed. Reversing the input wires of the pot does not work. If you add up the voltage outputs of assembly 2 they will always add up to 5 V unless something has failed.

So here is a description of what I need:
a circuit that creates two independent outputs from two  independent inputs. input number one will receive 0.9 - 4.5 V. Input number two will receive 4.5 - 0.9 V. The voltages of the inputs will always add up to 5 V unless something has failed. failure of the input voltages to add up to 5 V should cause the outputs to go to 0 V. output number one voltage should be equal to input number one. Output number 2 should always output half the voltage of output number one unless the combined voltage from the inputs deviates from 5 V. If a deviation happens then the circuit should be in a fail state and drop all output voltage to 0

Comment: Can this just be solved with a voltage buffer?  What does "independent" mean in this case?

Comment: Hello Lance and welcome ... can I ask if this is a university question?

Comment: The potentiometer assembly one and two both take 2 separate grounds, 2 separate 5v sources and 2 separate outputs. 6 wires total. This is for error checking. The system I am working with goes into a fail state if the voltage from pot 2 is not half the voltage from pot 1. The way the system that potentiometer assembly 2 worked is if the outputs from both potentiometers did not add up to 5v, it entered a fail state.
These are vehicle drive by wire throttle assemblies that work completely differently, so having the safety bypased by just halving the voltage from pot 1 is a bad idea.

Comment: If one is at 0.9 when the other is at 4.5 that adds up to 5.4 not 5, so you've already got a problem before you even start. What limits are there on the deviation from 5 V?

Comment: This is not a university question, just something I am trying to make work. I do not have a formal education in electronics.

Comment: GodJihyo
Apologies if I am not clear. Pot assy 1 has 2 outputs, output 2 is always half of output 1.
The other pot assy has outputs that always add up to 5v. Basically one output of this assy sweeps from high resistance to low, the other sweeps low to high. This is the opposite of pot assy 1

Comment: You could save a lot of words by drawing a graph of the transfer functions. Plot 0 - 330° on the X-axis (most pots only turn that much) and plot traces of what outputs you want on each wiper.

Comment: Transistor
I will make a video of the pot assemblies sweeping on a scope and post it here.

Comment: A graph will make it easier to see the whole picture and to calculate any resistor dividers, etc. A video doesn't make a great user requirement specification.

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your requirements? The output is 5V for inputs of 0.9 to 4.5 volts, and 4.5 to 0.9 volts.

[image: Inverse Voltages]

Comment: I believe this will do it, I will have to cut the output down by half but I know how to do that. Thanks! I will test this weekend and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your requirements, you will bypass one signal and short this to GND in case of a fault. The other signal needs to be inverted using a reference of 2.7 V as center, divided by 2 and also shorted to GND on faults. This will emulate the properties of your "assembly 1".

The fault condition is a deviation in the mean value of both input signals combined from 2.7 V within some small margin.

I included two buffer amplifiers because the circuit would affect a potentiometer as voltage source. Buffer output amplifiers may also be needed.

If rail to rail input and output opamps are used, the circuit can operate from a single 5 V supply.

This circuit should behave like that (not physically tested):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwkieA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>